Trigger function in parent or child window when location is local files
I am building an app with heavy media files.  I am at a crossroads. It either needs a hefty messy pre-caching system or it needs to be bundled together using an HTML to EXE app. The EXE app is preferable. However, the app has a control panel that runs in a second window.  At the moment, the user opens the control panel, moves it to another display monitor, and can control the main app.  The javascript uses window.opener.ParentFunction() to trigger anything it needs in the main app.
Window.opener works well, but only when the app is running online.  If it runs locally, it does not respond.   Is there a way to get parent or child windows to communicate on a local machine?  I could make this app work with the communication running in either direction, and I only need one direction.  I know browsers maintain strict rules on communication between windows.
In the main window (parent.html) I have this:
<html>
<body>
<h2>This is the parent page</h2>
<button onclick="OpenControlPanel()">Open Control Panel</button>
<div id="SomeText">ABCDE</div>

<script>
function OpenControlPanel(){
        ControlPanel = window.open('child.html', 'controls','height=480,width=640,left=200,top=200,location=no,menubar=no,resizeable=0,status=no,toolbar=no,titlebar=no');
    }

function DoSomething(){
        document.getElementById("SomeText").innerHTML="FGHIJ";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>

In the control panel (child.html) I have this:
<html>
<body>
<h2>This is the child page</h2>
<button onclick="window.opener.DoSomething()">hey Dad</button>
</body>
</html>

This works great.  But it only works from the server, not locally.

Does "running locally" now mean you are simply accessing those files in the browser via the file system, or are we talking about something you compiled into an EXE file?

My preference would be the HTML to EXE compiler route.  Accessing the files via the file system would be a solution as well.  The compilers I have used seem to embed a Chromium browser in the executable so the effect is almost the same in regard to coding.    I do not have a clear understanding of BLOB coding or related methods.  I am hoping there is a way for a browser to treat data on the local file system like it is being served.

I solved this using .postMessage.  Window.opener is still used, but by including postMessage in the child and then .addEventListener in the parent window, the trigger is passed through.
The parent window:
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
            document.getElementById('OutputInfo').innerHTML=event.data;
        }, true);
        
        var ChildWindow;
        function openChild() {
            ChildWindow = window.open('ChildWindow.html', 'controls','height=320,width=480,left=200,top=200,location=no,menubar=no,resizeable=0,status=no,toolbar=no,titlebar=no');
        }           
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>This is the parent window.</div>
    <br>
    <div onclick="openChild()" class="clickable">Open the child window</div>
    <br>    
    <div id="OutputInfo">&nbsp;</div>
</body>

and the child window:
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function DoSomething(a) {
            window.opener.postMessage(a, "*");
        }
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="DoSomething('Hey Dad')">hey Dad</button>   
</body> 

